# Promises in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I have been stuck on this for a few days. I have a react app that uses weather API. I do multiple get request (via loop) and get promises in return. What I need is after the promises are resolved the result (Array) sets the state. I think I should not chain `.then` because then the state would change multiple times based on the length of an Array.

My function responsible for API call goes like this:

```
apiRequest = (finalCitiesArray) => {
   let weatherArray =   finalCitiesArray.map((item) => {
  return (fetch("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id="+item.id+"&appid=API_KEY")
  .then(response => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(weather => {
   return weather;
  }))
})
this.setState({weather: weatherArray})}
```

I have tried to used async/await, create `new Promise` but I still did not manage to make it work properly. Any enlightenment would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: `weatherArray` is an array of promises that won't have resolved when you call `setState`. You need to use `Promise.all` to wait for them all to resolve (or one to reject) first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) for that.
The code using it would like this:

```
apiRequest = async (finalCitiesArray) => {
    const weatherArrayPromises = finalCitiesArray
        .map(item => {
            return fetch("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=" + item.id + "&appid=API_KEY")
                 .then(response => response.json());
         });

    const weatherArrayResults = await Promise.all(weatherArrayPromises); // <-- this is the line you're missing

    this.setState({ weather: weatherArrayResults });
}
```

Notice I've also remove the last `then` clause as it is not really required.